# PHP don't process through Nginx in windows WSL

Tags: php, linux, windows, nginx

I'm trying to make a local webserver with nginx php 7.1 and mariadb on windows WSL.
I tried a lot of things, use Kali, use Debian, use Ubuntu, change nginx port instead of 80, I found a few nginx config that I tried but none worked.

**My problem is that php don't process throught nginx.**
When I try to load a simple php page `<?php echo 'ok'; ?>` it load infinitly.
But when I restart php7.1-fpm, the page work ! (One time and only if I was trying to load it)

This is my actual default nginx config file :

```
server {
    listen 32000 default_server;
    listen [::]:32000 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

    #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
    #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
            #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
# I tried this too :
#fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
#fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
#fastcgi_index index.php;
#include fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
}
```

When I run `php index.php` this is working too. But on firefox nothing happen when I load this file. Everything is fine with full html page. I got the nginx welcome page too with no problems.

I don't know where to look anymore. Thanks for reading and if you have any answer, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Here is mine:

```
        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9123;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
          #  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME D:/web/html$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
            try_files = $uri @missing;
        }
```

Also make sure PHP-CGI is running (and on the right port).

Comment: Hi and thanks ! I have two questions, why port 9123? and how can I check if php-cgi is running ? I'm sorry I'm not a linux expert but trying to understand!

Comment: That is what port I configured php-cgi on, and by viewing your task manager, if your on a gui-less version of linux, use `ps | aux`

Comment: on the terminal that is

Comment: You're right... `sudo apt-get install php7.1-cli php7.1-fpm php7.1-curl php7.1-gd php7.1-mysql php7.1-mbstring` was my command line to install php
I installed php7.1-cgi but it doesn't appear in `ps -aux`.

Comment: because apt-get install doesn't start the process, it simply downloads the PHP7 package

Comment: Maybe I did too much mess on my config trying to get it work, I'll try a clean install. is my php command line for php ok if I add php-cgi or did I miss others things ?

Comment: you need to find the directory you installed it to, CD to that directory and call it via terminal. Then you can use `ps | aux` to get the list of running processes